# How to show syntax errors in an eclipse editor plugin while typing?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I'm writing an eclipse editor plugin for a custom file format by extending TextEditor for our language. I have also created builder for that language, now I want to indicate syntax errors (e.g. an illegal sequence of tokens)while typing in an eclipse editor plugin just like in the eclipse Java editor.

Some references suggested me to AddMarker. I had also implemented markers.
But currently on performing save & open editor, I am calling createMarkers method which validates syntax.

```
 public class MyEditor extends TextEditor {
      @Override
      protected void editorSaved() {
          super.editorSaved();
          validateAndMark();
      }

      public void validateAndMark() {
         Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                removeExistingMarkers(); //remove all existing markers
                valiadateFileAndMark(); //Validating file and adding my markers
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Currently its like this. But now I want to validate and add markers on typing like java editor.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: This is a very complex area. Have you read everything in the 'Editors' section of the 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' in the help? Look particularly at the annotation model.

Comment: Yes, I had gone through eclipse help section, but didn't find any related help from that. I have also tried to understand source code of Java Editor, but its too much complex for me.